# NetBeans git init ignore directories dist and build even if they are not in .gitignore

Tags: git, netbeans

I have two identical java NetBeans projects A and B; A is managed via git command line, B via Netbeans git integration.

```
A: via command line
git init
git add .

B: via NetBenas IDE (tested on version 7.3)
Team, Git, Initialize
Team, Git, Add
```

Results

```
A: all dir and files are tracked
B: all tracked but build/, dist/, nbproject/private/ directories.
```

This may also suit me, but I would rather decide myself. 
So I searched the .gitignore file that NetBeans must have created in order to ignore such files. 
But it doesn't work like this: it seems that it ignores build and dist directories on the basis of a non standard git entry, but something that comes from NetBeans.
Where is this Netbeans setting? I found the one shown in the screenshot above in the Netbeans options.
Unfortunately, once i've unchecked this flag, the result is ever the same (even if i start a new project from scratch!). 
At this point the question is: how do i *inlcude* dist files (if I wanted to) in git tracked files with netbeans git client?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and *so far* the only workaround that I've found is to open a git shell in the project folder and add the folder manually.

```
git add dist
git commit -m "dist added"
```

After this, you will be able to push your changes as usual from the netbeans IDE.

However I don't encourage such a thing as saving the dist folder. I believe it is more interesting to leave the code on the remote repo and have an automated building job that takes the code and makes the .jar.

Hope this helps!